# BindingList and ListBox behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox

I have a ListBox that is bound to a BindingList collection. This works great.

My only grief occurs when the first item enters the collection. The default behavior of the ListBox is to select that item - yet, this does not raise the SelectedIndexChanged event. I assume this is because the SelectedIndex is initially set to null; on becoming anything but null, the index isn't actually changed; rather assigned. How can I stop the default behavior of selecting (highlighting) the first initial item added to the ListBox?

If my assumption is wrong, please shed some light?

**Update**

Here is the core parts of my code thus far.

```
    public UavControlForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _controlFacade = new UavController.Facade.ControlFacade();
        UpdateFlightUavListBox();
    }

    private void UpdateFlightUavListBox()
    {
        lsbFlightUavs.DataSource = _controlFacade.GetFlightUavTally();
        lsbFlightUavs.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }

    private static BindingList<FlightUav> _flightUavTally = new BindingList<FlightUav>();
    public BindingList<FlightUav> FlightUavTally
    {
        get { return _flightUavTally; }
    }

    public void AddFlightUav(double[] latLonAndAlt)
    {
        FlightUav flightUav = new FlightUav();
        flightUav.Latitude = latLonAndAlt[0];
        flightUav.Longitude = latLonAndAlt[1];
        flightUav.Altitude = latLonAndAlt[2];
        _flightUavTally.Add(flightUav);

        UtilStk.InjectAircraftIntoStk(flightUav.Name);
        flightUav.SetFlightDefaults();
        PlayScenario();
    }
```

**Update:**

So, setting `lsbFlightUavs.SelectedIndex = -1` solves the problem. The above method `AddFlightUav()` is called from a button's OnClick handler in a second form from the main form. How can I call `lsbFlightUavs.SelectedIndex = -1` from this second form when the `AddFlightUav()` method returns? I know I can make the ListBox static, but that seems like bad practice to me.. what would be a more elegant solution?

Comment: Can you post the code where you assign the DataSource of the BindingSource and ListBox, and where you add a new item? Incidentally, SelectedIndex is an int so it will never be null: it initialises to -1

Comment: @ Stuart Dunkeld, you're right about the SelectedIndex being an int. I will post the code later tonight.

Comment: I have some further discussions here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/6c90af6d-e1f9-4890-90a9-260abcfc1980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WinForms, I implemented the Singleton pattern. This enabled me to access the ListBox control from my second form.

**Form 1**

```
private static UavControlForm _instance = new UavControlForm();
private UavControlForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();   
}
public static UavControlForm Instance
{
    get { return _instance; }
}
public ListBox FlightUavListBox
{
    get { return lsbFlightUavs; }
}
```

**Form 2**

```
UavControlForm.Instance.FlightUavListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```